# How to like a photo via Instagram's API

Tags: c#, asp.net, instagram-api

The following code results in this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("access_token", Session["AT"].ToString());

WebClient client = new WebClient();
var result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1144917811612429247_571137889/likes", "POST", parameters);

var response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if access_token is valid? You can check more details in response. It looks like `{
    "meta": {
        "error_type": "OAuthParameterException",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "Missing access_token URL parameter."
    }
}` or something similar. You can check where is real problem

Comment: hi i think i found this problem. i start a submission in Permission tab in instagram.com